# Uniform integrability of a sequence of random variables defined by a recursive relation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

I have an i.i.d sequence $(u_j)_{j\in \mathbb{Z}_+}$ with zero mean and finite variance, say $\sigma^2$. Furthermore, I have another random variable $X_0$ (defined on the same probability space) which is independent of $(u_j)_{j\in \mathbb{Z}_+}$. It is also given that $E[X_0^2] < \infty$. Finally, I have a real-valued constant $\theta$ with $\lvert\theta\rvert < 1$.

Here is the recursive relation mentioned in the title.
$$X_j = \theta X_{j-1} + u_j \quad j=1,2,\ldots$$

I want to show that $(X_{j}^2)_{j\in \mathbb{Z}_+}$ is uniformly integrable. Since higher moments ($>2$) of $u_1$ do not necessarily exist, the road to uniform integrability via $L^p$-boundedness ($p>1$) is blocked. Can someone help out?

Comment: An approach is to *impose stationarity*, that is, to consider some independent copy $(v_j)$ of $(u_j)$ and to define $(Y_j)$ recursively by $Y_j=\theta Y_{j-1}+u_j$ for every $j\geqslant1$, with $$Y_0=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\theta^jv_j.$$ Then $(Y_j)$ is identically distributed and $Y_0^2$ is integrable hence $(Y_j^2)$ is uniformly integrable. Furthermore, $|X_j-Y_j|=\theta^j|X_0-Y_0|$ hence $X_j-Y_j\to0$ in $L^2$. This is enough to imply that $(X_j)$ is uniformly integrable, do you see why?

Comment: @Did Should it be $v_j$ instead of $u_j$ in the recursive relation for $Y$?

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did Oh sorry I get that part now. For the last part I can make the difference $E[X_j^2] - E[Y_j^2]$ arbitrarily small. This implies of course that $E[X_j^2]$ is bounded. But this is not enough. Is there a particular characterization of UI property that works here?

Comment: @Did Ok I think I figured it out. $X_j^2 -Y_j^2 \to 0$ both in $L^1$ and in probability. This can only happen if $X_j^2 -Y_j^2$ is UI. Finally, the sum of two UI collections is UI. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $c_j:=\mathbb E\left[X_j^2\right]$. By the assumptions, we have 
$$c_j=\theta^2c_{j-1}+\sigma^2,\quad j\geqslant 1,$$
hence taking $R\geqslant\max\left\{\sigma^2/(1-\theta^2),\mathbb E\left[X_0^2\right]\right\}$, we can see by induction that $c_j\leqslant R$ for each $j\geqslant 0$.

Now, using boundedness of $\left(c_j\right)_{j\geqslant 1}$ and the recursion relation, that for each $A$, we have 
$$\sup_{j\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[X_j^2\mathbf 1(A)\right]\leqslant 
\frac 1{1-\theta^2}\left(2\theta\sqrt R\sup_{j\geqslant 1}\left(\mathbb E\left[u_j^2\mathbf 1(A)\right]\right)^{1/2}+\sup_{j\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[u_j^2\mathbf 1(A)\right]\right).$$
Indeed, for each $j\geqslant 1$, 
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[X_j^2\mathbf 1(A)\right]&=\theta^2\mathbb E\left[X_{j-1}^2\mathbf 1(A)\right]+2\theta\mathbb E\left[X_{j-1}u_j\mathbf 1(A)\right]+
\mathbb E\left[u_j^2\mathbf 1(A)\right]\\
&\leqslant \theta^2\sup_{j\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[X_{j}^2\mathbf 1(A)\right]+2\theta\sup_{j\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[X_{j-1}u_j\mathbf 1(A)\right]+
\sup_{j\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[u_j^2\mathbf 1(A)\right],
\end{align}
then use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. 
Now, since the sequence $(u_j^2)_{j\geqslant 1}$ is uniformly integrable, we get the wanted conclusion.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but would you be able to explain the last inequality?

Comment: @Calculon I have added more details.